# Jquery background slider repeats first image

Tags: javascript, jquery

DISCLAIMER:I am clueless to javascript and jquery. I use code snippets to get by on personal projects.

I have a background image slider (fader) that I'm using for my website. The main problem is that the first image displays twice when it first starts up and only when it first starts up. Looking for a way to have it not do that.

And also preload the images while I'm at it... Any help will be appreciated!

The test site is below followed by the relevant (I think) code. Thanks in advance!

tjoseph.com/tjoseph_2017

HTML

```
    <body>
<div class="fader">

</div>
    <div id="textbox">
        <div id="text">
        <p id="name">Travis Hoffman-Joseph Photography</p>
        <p><a id="email" href="mailto:develop@vo88pro.com">develop@vo88pro.com</a></p>
        <p>917.952.0596</p>
        </div>
        <div id="contact_social">
    <ul>

      <a href="http://tjoseph13.tumblr.com" target="new" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('_tumblr','','images/over_tumblr.gif',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
          <img id="_tumblr" src="images/_tumblr.gif" alt="tumblr"></a>

        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/tjoseph_vo88" target="new" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('instagram','','images/over_instagram.gif',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img id="instagram" src="images/_instagram.gif" alt="instagram"></a>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">all rights reserved © 2017</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    .fader
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -99;

}
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

  var count = 0;
  var images = ["bg_images/bg_img01.jpg","bg_images/bg_img02.jpg","bg_images/bg_img03.jpg"];
  var image = $(".fader");

  image.css("background-image","url("+images[count]+")");

  setInterval(function(){
    image.fadeOut(250, function(){
      image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");
      image.fadeIn(250);
    });
    if(count == images.length)
    {
      count = 0;
    }
  },2500);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `fader` div has the `bg_img01.jpg` as a background image on page load, so when the Javascript fires, it is loading the same image that's already being used on load. Changing the initial declaration of the `count` variable to 1 should resolve the issue.

```
var count = 1;
```

Comment: I tried changing the count to 1 but now it does the same thing with the second image... when I remove "background-image" from image.css, it displays a black screen and then starts the script without repeating. Or when I change var count to 3, I will get a black a the same black screen then the script without repeating. Is there a way to set the on load image?